# How to add two screens to the navigation of the React Native app without showing them in the TabBar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, tabbar

I need the user registration and login screens to not be displayed in the `TabBar` of the App
I have a simple application in which I am trying to have two types of user interface, one for a guest mode and one for when the user is authenticated.
I have created a navigation for each `authentication` conditional, so that the TabBar corresponding to each state of the application is displayed, or guest mode or authenticated mode. I also have a `TabBar` Component to show the Icons of each of the Navigations.

The problem arises when I want to add the `LoginScreen` and `RegisterScreen` screens since I can't access them.

I have tried to create a third `Navigation` (AuthNavigator ) to manage these screens, and finally got access but they show up on the TabBar,
But this cannot be, these screens cannot be accessed from the `TabBar`

I need them to be in the navigation, but not show on the `TabBar`.

In the `TabBar` file these screens are not added, so the `Icon` is not shown, but the title is

I have tried using `options={{ tabBarVisible: false }}` , but this has no effect

Also `display = "none"` without success.

I have looked for solutions in Google and I have not found anything.

I want to show my navigation system to guide me what I'm doing. wrong and can correct my mistakes.

---------  App.js ---------

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import GuestNavigator from './navigation/GuestNavigator'
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator'

const App = () => {
 
  const isUserAuthenticated = false; 

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isUserAuthenticated ? (
        <AppNavigator />
      ) : (
        <GuestNavigator />
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
export default App
```

**---This is the navigation in GUEST mode---**

----  GuestNavigator.JS -------

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import TabBar from '../components/TabBar';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const GuestNavigator = ({ handleLogin }) => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <TabBar {...props} />}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="SampleNotas" component={SampleNotasScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="SampleCuras" component={SampleCurasScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="SamplePerfil" component={SamplePerfilScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Login"
        options={{ tabBarVisible: false }}
        children={() => <LoginScreen handleLogin={handleLogin} />}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
export default GuestNavigator;
```

***--This is the navigation in the AUTHENTICATED mode --***

------ AppNavigator.JS ---------

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import TabBar from '../components/TabBar';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const AppNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <TabBar {...props} />}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Notas" component={NotasScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="CrearNota" component={CrearNotaScreen} options={{ tabBarVisible: false }} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Curas" component={CurasScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Recordatorios" component={RecordatoriosScreen}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="EditProfile" component={EditarProfileScreen} options={{ tabBarVisible: false }} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
export default AppNavigator
```

And I have also created a navigation system only for Login and Register

-------  AuthNavigator.js ----------

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import LoginScreen from '../screens/AuthScreens/LoginScreen'
import RegisterScreen from '../screens/AuthScreens/RegisterScreen'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

const AuthNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={LoginScreen}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Register"
          component={RegisterScreen}
          options={{
            title: 'Registro',
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default AuthNavigator
```

Of course if I remove LoginScrein from the GuestNavigator navigation, I get error:

**ERROR  The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Login"} was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'Login'?
If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.
This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.**

And I also show the TabBar although it shows the icon and these screens are not added.
----- TabBar.js -----------

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

const TabBar = ({ state, descriptors, navigation, isUserAuthenticated }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', height: 60, backgroundColor: '#F3F9F5' }}>
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const { options } = descriptors[route.key];

        const onPress = () => {
          const event = navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabPress',
            target: route.key,
          });

          if (!event.defaultPrevented) {
            navigation.navigate(route.name);
          }
        };

        const isFocused = state.index === index;
        const color = isFocused ? '#08A438' : 'black';

        let iconName;
        if (!isUserAuthenticated) {
          // Iconos para el modo invitado
          if (route.name === 'Home') {
            iconName = 'home';
          } else if (route.name === 'SampleNotas') {
            iconName = 'list';
          } else if (route.name === 'SampleCuras') {
            iconName = 'medkit';
          } else if (route.name === 'SamplePerfil') {
            iconName = 'person';
          }
        } else {
          // Iconos para el modo autenticado
          if (route.name === 'Notas') {
            iconName = 'notes';
          } else if (route.name === 'Curas') {
            iconName = 'medkit';
          } else if (route.name === 'Recordatorios') {
            iconName = 'alarm';
          } else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
            iconName = 'person';
          }
        }

        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={index}
            onPress={onPress}
            style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}
          >
            <Icon name={iconName} size={24} color={color} />
            <Text style={{ color }}>{route.name}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
};
export default TabBar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to resolve this add Guestnavigator to AuthNavigator like this:

```
const AuthNavigator = ({}) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="GuestStack" component={GuestNavigator}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen}/>
   </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

refactor `App.js` to:

```
const App = () => {    
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isAuth ? <AuthNavigator /> : <AppNavigator />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

and don't forget to remove the login tab from `GuestNavigator`.

Comment: Thank you very much @guiav, I've been trying to correct this for days. I will put a bounty to reward it, now I will start to implement authentication and I have the same problem with two screens. There are two screens for editing the profile and adding things that shouldn't be on the TabBar. I'll try to fix it with this lesson you've given me on Navigation. If I can't, I'll mention you in a question so you can help me. Thank you

Comment: it will work for you like above, put the profile screen on top of screens that will use it.